# How do I edit Facebook wall posts using RestFB?

Tags: java, facebook-graph-api, restfb

I'm writing a simple Java program that gets/edits/deletes the wall posts of a Facebook group. I'm able to get and delete any wall post that I choose, but I don't know how to edit a particular post.

Here's my attempted solution

```
    // Get all posts on wall
    Connection<Post> restFbPosts = facebookClient.fetchConnection("fakepage/posts", Post.class);

    for (Post post : restFbPosts.getData()) {
        // Want to edit the post with message "test"
        if (post.getMessage().equals("test")) {
            post.setMessage("test post is modified");

            facebookClient.deleteObject(post.getId());
            facebookClient.publish("fakepage/feed", FacebookType.class, Parameter.with("message", post.getMessage()));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Now i suggest powerful tip for you edit particular wall post. That's Facebook4J. It's very easy to use.

Post to wall:

```
PostUpdate update = new PostUpdate("Hello World");
String returnPostId=facebook.postFeed(userID,update);//or Group_ID
```

Delete Post, You can delete more object like Photo, Comment

```
facebook.deletePost(postId);
```

Get Message:

```
facebook.getMessage(messageId)
```

For more infomation, see [Facebook4J](http://facebook4j.org/en/code-examples.html)